# Random Vector/point/Position inside Sphere in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, vector

Whats a good and performant way of creating a list of random vectors inside a given radius/sphere?

the random vector node (with scale set to 1) unfortunately creates vectors ranging from (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1), which results in a cube like shape. When changed to `Normalized Vector`, all vectors have a magnitude of exactly 1, resulting in uniform distribution on the surface of a sphere.

How can I achieve random vectors with a magnitude ranging from 0 to 1?

Is there a better way than creating a loop of a single normalized vector with a random scale?

Comment: What about multiplying with .5 and adding 1 ? 

Comment: I don't want vectors in the positive quadrant, I want vectors with a maximum but variable length. For example the vector (-1, -1, -1) has a length of 1.73 but i only want vectors in the range of 0 to 1. The Normalize Vector option in the node results in vectors of length 1 and exactly length 1. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spherical distribution of random points inside sphere the actual way: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408276/sampling-uniformly-distributed-random-points-inside-a-spherical-volume)

[image]

Fast and simplified version:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The cube root is just for a uniform distribution, right? (I actually don't need that, but nice to know, its that simple)
I also like the scaling afterwards instead of using a loop, didn't think of that.

Comment: Yes cube root is for uniform distribution

Answer (score 0):

So seems like my first (second) idea works great and performs really well:

I use a `Random Number` inside a loop to control the scale of a single `Random Vector` node. The Random Vector is set to `Normalized Vector`.
I also added a basic setup to have some control over the seeds.

**Node Setup and comparison to the native random vector nodes:**

[image]